# How to set the document root in Virtualmin sub server?

Tags: apache, subdomain, centos6, webmin, virtualmin

I have a Centos 6.10 server running Webmin/Virtualmin  in a dedicated box. I have a few subdomains running under a main parent domain. These sub domains - sub servers as they are called under Virtualmin serve the main page.

I have edited the `httpd.conf` under  `/etc/httpd/conf` to reflect the `document root` like so:
`/home/parent/public_html/subdomain1`
I also hunted down a numbered text file containing some directives here: `/etc/webmin/virtual-server/domains/xxxxxxxx`
And modified the document root as above.
Still the server when asked to serve https://subdomain1 it shows only the pages of domains.

I have searched everywhere for the hidden Apache directive which points the subdomain to the main server to no avail. What do I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you PauloBoaventura for taking the time to write. I finally sorted out the issue. The primary domain has a dedicated IP address and all the subdomains shared the same IP address. But I changed the subdomains IP address to the default IP address and now all the subdomains are working as they should. A lesson learnt with Virtualmin : - small things however insignificant they may appear to be - they have a bearing on the final result.

Answer (score 0):

In virtualmin, it often does not recognize the subdomain in the apache configuration.

Try to create a separate domain, being a sub-domain.

1subdomain.domain.com

Good luck! Send news about your progress ...